# doctrine remove entity with association

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hello I am working with Symfony2 and Doctrine and I can not make a thing.

I have a product entity and another entity provider:

```
Product * ----------- 1 provider
```

If I delete a provider and could leave all bone products supplier null foreign key.

```
result 
products provider:
    product1 (id,name,desc,id_provider=null)
    product2 (id,name,desc,id_provider=null)
    product3 (id,name,desc,id_provider=null)
```

I've looked cascade remove but what it does is remove products and is not what I want.

greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `onDelete: SET NULL` in your JoinColumn instead of `onDelete: CASCADE`.

Comment: thanks for yours answers. Juan sosa , you could put some code? a greeting.

Comment: I don´t know which format are you using to define your entities (yml, xml, php, annotations) so I can´t put any code. However, a quick search on Google for "doctrine onDelete set null" should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

In your delete action in the controller, fetch all the joined products for a provider and set their keys to null.